# I converted a few wmv files to mp4 and I want to compare if the duration of the files are same but I need help

Tags: command-line, bash, video

I tried running this:

`find -wholename './*/*.wmv' -exec sh -c '[[ $(exiftool -Duration "$1") == $(exiftool -Duration "${1%.*}.mp4") ]] && echo "Equal" || echo "Not equal $1"' _ {} \;`

But its says command not found. My wmv and mp4 files are named the same except for the extension.

I am using Ubuntu 20.04. Please any help would be awesome

Also, I would prefer a code that can be run on a single line in terminal

Comment: `[[` is a bash thing, it won't work with `sh`.

Comment: Could you please suggest me a way to correctly do it? I'm a newbie here

Comment: Use `bash` instead of `sh`.

Comment: Thanks, it worked!

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by [@muru](https://askubuntu.com/users/158442/muru)

`find -wholename './*/*.wmv' -exec bash -c '[[ $(exiftool -Duration "$1") == $(exiftool -Duration "${1%.*}.mp4") ]] && echo "Equal" || echo "Not equal $1"' _ {} \;`

works perfectly